# how to get json data in django sent using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django

i am using jquery to send json data that contains array of elements like this

```
$('#brand_category').click(function(event){

        category = $("input:checkbox[name=category]:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
        }).get();

        brand = $("input[type='radio']:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
        }).get();

        parameter.push({
          brand :   brand,
          category: category
        });

        var json = JSON.stringify(parameter)

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "{% url 'seller_details' %}",
            data: {'parameter[]' : json , csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}'},
            success: function(data){
            },
            error:function (response, error){
            }
            });
```

and in the view i am collecting the data like this

```
brand_category = self.request.POST.get('parameter[]')
print brand_category
```

this prints the data as this

```
[{"brand":["spykar"],"category":["Women Clothing","Dresses"]},{"brand":["Madame"],"category":["Women Clothing","Dresses"]}]
```

then i tried to loop through the json like this

```
for list in list_data:
                brand =  list_data['brand']
                print brand
                categories = list_data['category']
                print categories
```

but i am getting the error as this

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

how can i loop through the json data to get the list of brands and categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outer loop is a list, and then you loop through each dictionary in the list. Also, you have to convert the string to a python object.

```
import json
brand_category = self.request.POST.get('parameter[]')
Lbrand_category = json.loads(brand_category)
for D in Lbrand_category:
   brand,categories = D['brand'],D['category']
```

Note: if you want only the brand string, without the list, use:

```
brand,categories = D['brand'][0],D['category']
```

Comment: in the first one it throws string 'indices must be integers'

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this AJAX Request (Its more clear):

```
$('#brand_category').click( sendAjax );

function sendAjax()
{
  var category = $("input:checkbox[name='category']:checked").val();
  var brand = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();

  var data = { "category" : category, "brand" : brand, "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : '{{csrf_token}}' }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "{% url 'seller_details' %}",
    data: data,
    success: function(data)
    {
      //console.log(data) // Print the response of Django or see this in "Network" request, F12 Chrome
    },
    error:function (response, error)
    {
    }
  });
}
```

View:

```
category = request.POST['category']
print category

brand    = request.POST['brand']
print brand
```

List data of brands in JavaScript:

```
var data = {} //This is a empty object named data
data.brans = [];
```

and then you need create a for select all brands

```
for ("list of brands"){
  brand_name = logic
  data.brands.push(brand_name)
} //This is only a idea
```

Comment: How will i come to know that which brand has which category ?

Comment: what i am trying to do this a user can select multiple brands and each brand can have multiple categories

Comment: well, you miss something in the question. If print brand_category gives you a list, the prev code should have worked, if it's a string, then this one. Tested both

Comment: I wanna ask a question...is this a correct way to send data in such a scenario?

Comment: Mmmm the category have many brands? See this [link](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/django-create-a-queryset-from-a-list-preserving-order.html)

Comment: Ok select the list of brands, and this have a ManyToMany to categories, select the queryset in this [link](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/django-create-a-queryset-from-a-list-preserving-order.html) and then you need a for in categories in your template, i think, this method is very clear